# Remove first 2 columns from first row of a file

Tags: text-processing, command

I am looking for a command to remove first 2 columns from the first row of a file. The delimiter for the columns is a pipe. Number of columns vary.

we just need to blindly remove first 2 columns. sample below.

input:
col1|col2|col3|col4

output
col3|col4

Comment: Could you edit your question and provide a sample of the file?

Comment: How many columns does the file have? Should the two 1st fields be made blank (so `foo|bar|baz` becomes `||baz`) or should the output line only have N-2 columns (so that  `foo|bar|baz` becomes `baz`)? Please [edit] your question and include an example of your input and desired output.

Comment: @sunshine737 - unless you _are_ the OP how do you know what the sample input and desired output look like ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest command is

```
sed '1s/^[^|]*|[^|]*|//g' input > output
```

This `sed` command will *only on line 1* do the substitution.

For this input:

```
foo|bar|baz|doo|bee|doo
123|456
789|101|112
```

it will produce that output:

```
baz|doo|bee|doo
123|456
789|101|112
```

Answer (score 0):

try this command

```
head -2 inputFile.txt | cut -d "|" -f 3- > outputFile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The cut command should do the job if I guess at what you are referring to.

```
echo "foo|bar|baz" | cut -d"|" -f3
```

So if you are only wanting to edit the first row then use the head command as well.

```
head -n1 filename | cut -d"|" -f3
```

You could also use sed to do the job.

```
head -n1 filename | sed 's/^.*|.*|//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will cut out the first 2 pipe-delimited fields of line 1, and copy the rest of the file (line 2 onward) without changes.

```
(head -n 1 input | cut -d '|' -f 3- ; tail -n +2 input) > output
```

A slightly more efficient but syntactically trickier way to do it is:

```
{ head -n 1 input | cut -d '|' -f 3- ; tail -n +2 input; } > output
```

Comment: With `{..}` you could golf it shorter: `{ head -n 1 | cut -d '|' -f 3-; cat; } <infile >outfile`